# Facebook Rate limit solutions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Im trying to **create ads** in facebook using **python sdk**. (15000 ads to be exact)

Im hiting rate limit after I create 10 ads (i.e 10 create-ad requests)

I tried putting delay between each request. (1 second delay)

The error im getting is:

`message': 
'Calls to this api have exceeded the rate limit.', 'code': 613, 'error_subcode': 1487742`

Do you know what delay I should put. Or better, what I should do to avoid rate limit.

It'll be very helpfull to know any experience on this.

Comment: Have you read the documentation to begin with? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/best-practices#adsoverview

Comment: Hey @cbroe. Thanks for replying. Im quite familiar with the facebook docs. But facebook does not provide any numbers. Thats why I wanted to know if anybody who has faced similar problems, solved it in some way.

Comment: Their docs don't mention the exact number of calls and the rate. They say the API access is scored using their algorithm (which takes cpu usage, etc). This makes it difficult to come up with a strategy that bypasses it.

Comment: @MevinBabu yes, but in general your strategy should be to make as few requests as possible to begin with, and not do it the other way around and try to figure out how much you can “get away with”. It also says, _“Number of ad creation is limited for a given ad account based on the daily spend limit.”_ and _“You can also increase the daily spend limit.”_, so if that is the particular limit they run into in this instance, that could be one possible “solution” …